# Letter Combinations of a Phone Number Everything is correct except 1 test where input is just ""

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

[image: Failes test case SS]

I have returned an empty String but the desired output shows I should return nothing.
How can I return nothing?
Pls, refer to the attached image, you'll understand the question.

Below I am adding my code pls tell me which part I can improve-

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
        String mapping[]={"","","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
        int num=0;
        try{
        num=Integer.parseInt(digits);
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
            System.out.print("error");
        }
        List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
        // List<String> res=new ArrayList<>();
        ans = helper(num,mapping);
        return ans;
    }
    public List<String> helper(int num, String mapping[]){
        if(num<=0){
            List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
            ans.add("");
            return ans;
        }
        List<String> smallAns=new ArrayList<>();
        int myNum=num%10;
        smallAns=helper(num/10, mapping);
        String s=mapping[myNum];
        List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
        ans=appendStr(s, smallAns);
        return ans;
    }
    public List<String> appendStr(String s, List<String> res){
        List<String> out=new ArrayList<>();
        int l=s.length();
        int i=0;
        while(i<l){
            for(int j=0;j<res.size();j++){
                String toAdd=res.get(j)+s.charAt(i);
                out.add(toAdd);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add the empty string to the list in `helper`. Just return `ans` without adding anything to it.

Comment: The only part of the image that's relevant to your question was the bit which showed what the output should be, if the input is an empty string.  But that was the one part that you chopped off, and replaced with the weather forecast.  Why?

Comment: `return List.of()`

Comment: Issue is reolved when I added this block of code in letterCombinations() method.
```        if(digits.length()==0){
            List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
            return ans;
        }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this block of code now it's working

```
if(digits.length()==0){
    List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
    return ans;
}
```

The above block of code is added letterCombinations function which will return empty array list if the String provided by user is empty as required.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
        if(digits.length()==0){
            List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
            return ans;
        }
        String mapping[]={"","","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
        int num=0;
        try{
        num=Integer.parseInt(digits);
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.print("error");
        }
        List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
        ans = helper(num,mapping);
        return ans;
    }
    public List<String> helper(int num, String mapping[]){
        if(num<=0){
            List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
            ans.add("");
            return ans;
        }
        List<String> smallAns=new ArrayList<>();
        int myNum=num%10;
        smallAns=helper(num/10, mapping);
        String s=mapping[myNum];
        List<String> ans=new ArrayList<>();
        ans=appendStr(s, smallAns);
        return ans;
    }
    public List<String> appendStr(String s, List<String> res){
        List<String> out=new ArrayList<>();
        int l=s.length();
        int i=0;
        while(i<l){
            for(int j=0;j<res.size();j++){
                String toAdd=res.get(j)+s.charAt(i);
                out.add(toAdd);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to notice what you changed (and why you did it). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75062495/edit) your answer and add a short explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Done. @FedericoklezCulloca is it okay now?

Comment: @Shubham yes, it's fine now